# Visual Studio 2010 - Exclude file type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to exclude all files with a dedicated file extension e.g. *.ipp from C++ build process ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you tell us more compiler (I guess, it's VS 2010, but still) / OS and what's the reason you want to do that. Say, it looks to me you can just not include those files into your project in the first place.

Comment: @biocomp: Yes it is Win/VS2010. I have multiple C++ template classes were the implementation is within the *.ipp file. Until now each *.ipp file is excluded from build by hand. It would be more simple to define a global compiler rule to exclude *.ipp files from compile.

Comment: Well, now I wonder how you include files in the first place. I guess, you do that in some kind of automatic way. Depending on that, there may be different options on excluding file extensions. Could you tell us how you include files into project? Even better, could you provide minimal project file with repro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok in the meantime I figured it out on my own:

Environment:
VS2010 / C++ project with templates. Templates are declared in *.h and implemented in *.cpp. Each *.cpp file is set to "Exclude from build = Yes"

Problem:
Each time a new template implementation is added the corresponding *.cpp must be manual set to "Exclude from build = Yes"

What I want:
A build rule to exclude ALL template implementation files from build process.

Action:
Renamed *.cpp file within the "Solution Explorer" to *.ipp.

Result:
When "Exclude from build = No" file is compiled even it has no *.cpp extension.

Option A:
Set each individual *.ipp file to "Exlcude from build = Yes" -> This is no option for me !

Option B:
Remove the *.ipp from the solution and add it again. Within *.vcxproj file is then added as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="..\..\src\foo.ipp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and therefore not compiled anymore.